# how to use AutobahnJs to send a message to a specified client?

Tags: websocket, autobahn

I need a scheme of push message server.

By now I choose AutobahnJs + AutobahnPython scheme.

use websocket of html5 by AutobahnJs Library connect to server which use by AutobahnPython

now, clientA ,clientB,clientC connect to server.

APPS want to send a message to clientA. How to do it?

this is my flow:
APPS disguised as a clientD to connect to server.

in javascript, use subscribe channel, every client use the same subscribe channel. 
clientD publish a message to channel(the same to subscribe channel), the server messaging to all client who subscribe this channel.

Here is a problem, I need APPS(clientD) to send a message to clientA only, not every client who subscribe.how to do this?

Maybe my flow is incorrect. any help and more scheme?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by providing the WAMP session ID in the eligible parameter when doing the publish:

http://autobahn.ws/js/reference#Session_publish

The WAMP session ID can be get in AutobahnJS by calling sessionid() on the session object.

http://autobahn.ws/js/reference#Session_sessionid

Your overall scheme is correct for your use case: all clients subscribe to 1 topic, but then specify only a dedicated receiver eligible to receive a published message.

Comment: 1.I don't understand params of exclude and eligible in Session.publish ( topic, event, exclude, eligible ).How do i get other's sessionID? I'm just able to get sessionID of myself. 2.Example of WAMP Session Authentication is unclick. How to use Session Authentication. 3.When i refresh webpage, the session ID was changed, How to fixed sessionid where refresh or reopen webpage? 4.How does server side(autoAbhnPython) control(get and store) client's sessions? Sorry,so many questions to bother you,But I ready need help, thanks a lot!

Comment: The session ID is specific to 1 WAMP session and has lifetime only for that session. When you reload/leave a page that opened a WebSocket connection, that connection, and hence the WAMP session disappears. The session ID is randomly generated by the WAMP server when a WAMP client connects. Exclude/eligible are optional parameters that contain session IDs of active WAMP session. For a client to get the session ID of another client, that needs to be communicated as part of a RPC response or in a PubSub event payload. If you have more questions, maybe better use the mailing list, since ..

Comment: I visited your site , and have viewed all of tutorials about AutobahnPython, I am a NEW pythomer, by now ,i just can imitate the examples, so outside examples, I know nothing. i want a feature that can hanlder session, when a client disconnect,the server can handle this action. BTW: how do I get the mailing list? is it google forum?